# бинарный(двоичный) поиск для String

Tags: java, строки

Всем привет, понимаю как написать бинарный поиск по массиву, но не могу понять как этот поиск сделать по String чтобы найти char символ.
Код для поиска позиции слова в массиве -

```
public static int charSearch(String word, char a, int lB, int uB){
            if(lB > uB){
                return -1;
            }
            int med = lB + (uB - lB) /2;
            int cmp = Character.compare(a, word.charAt(med));
            if( cmp < 0){
                return charSearch(word,a,lB, med-1);
            }
            if(cmp > 0){
                return charSearch(word,a, med +1, uB);
            }
            return med;
        }
```

Вызов метода -

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
         char h = 's';
         String a = "Toschibaabr";
System.out.println(charSearch(a, h,0,a.length()-1)); //возвращает 2, а должен 3
System.out.println(charSearch("Topchibaasbr", h,0,a.length()-1)); //возвращает -1, а должен 10
System.out.println(charSearch("Ksojan",'a',0,a.length()-1)) //возвращает 4, а должен 5
System.out.println(charSearch("Ksojan",'n',0,a.length()-1)) ////возвращает -1, а должен 6
}
```

Comment: в чем для вас принципиальная разница между `myString.charAt(i)` и `myArray[i]` ? С чем конкретно сложности?

Comment: @tym32167 проблема именно в этой строке, не получается ее переписать на charAt или же думаю слишком сложно и не вижу простого решения - int cmp = search.compareTo(arr[med]); На счет Вашего вопроса про разницу, в линейном поиске, а именно если использовать for или whilе, то проблем вообще никаких с этим, но в бинарном не понимаю как вывести позицию искомого элемента

Comment: я не понимаю, что значит `не получается ее переписать на charAt`? Покажите пример вашего кода, покажите место, которое работает не так, как вам надо. Добавьте эту всю информацию в вопрос. Пока что ваш воарос непонятен - вы показываете код, который работает, и задаете вопросы по какому то коду, который вы не показали - это бессмысленная трата времени, будьте предельно конкретны. Фраза `не получается ее переписать на charAt` мне не говорит ни о чем, так как я знаю, как переписать, и не понимаю, где там вообще может быть затык.

Comment: @tym32167 дополнил в главной теме

Comment: Вы можете пояснить, в чем смысл переменной `int cmp`? Для чего она тут вообще нужна в алгоритме?

Comment: Попытайтесь обдумать, для чего нужно `int cmp ...` и что делать с символом на нужной позиции. Внимание - `char a` же должен участвовать в сравнении

Comment: @tym32167 для сравнения и в зависимости от подсчитанного значения будет вызван след. соответственный метод. Я понимаю, что мной переписано неправильно, но как заставить метод тогда "шагать" дальше?. С массивом мне понятно, но с String нет. Я много уже на самом деле что перепробовал. Моя проблема, как новичка,что я ищу нестандартные подходы, хотя задачу можно было бы решить намного проще и не заморачиваться.. В общем смотрю совсем не в ту сторону, которую надо

Comment: @MBo Да, так оно и есть.. вот что я дописал сейчас - if(word.charAt(med) == a){
                return med;}  ..но проблема заставить шагать метод по строке осталась....

Comment: Какая проблема? Чем отличаются индексы символов в строке от индексов элементов в массиве?

Comment: @MBo повторяете самый первый коммент под вопросом :)

Comment: @MBo реализовать сам проход. Индексы по сути ничем не отличаются, но как сравнивать char-ы для cmp, ведь они не массив обьектов? Нужна просто идея, которой мне от малого опыта не хватает.... Или же я просто не вижу простое решение, которое у меня под носом, видимо, как я понимаю с комментариев.

Comment: вам надо: 1) Иметь первый char , который ищете (переменная `a`) 2) Иметь второй char, с которым сравниваете (`ord.charAt(med)`) 3) Сравнить их методом, например, `Character.compare(первый, второй)` 4) Записать результат сравнения в `cmp`

Comment: никто не может понять вашу проблему, потому что для нас это очевидно. Поглядите на мой комментарий и скажите, с каким пунктом у вас сложности?

Comment: С пунктом 3 у меня проблема, сравнить два чара для записи в пункт 4

Comment: Ну, я вам дал прямо метод, котоый надо вызвать. Осталось его только написать в вашем коде. `int cmp = Character.compare(a, mystring.charAt(mid));`

Comment: @tym32167 Благодарю, все работает, но метод почему-то возвращает неправильную позицию char  (минус 1 или позицию меньше на 1 от правильной).. Если не сложно взгляните на код сверху.. я его перезалил..

Comment: Когда вы говорите, что метод возвращает не то, указывайте также данные, с которыми вы его вызываете, что ожидаете от него и что он возвращает.  И имейте в виду, что в массивах индекс начинается от 0

Comment: @tym32167 перезалил снова

Comment: Бинарный поиск работает только на отсортированных данных. То есть если это массив чисел - то числа должны быть отсортированы. Если строка - то все символы в строке должны идти строго по порядку. Вы не можете запускать бинарный поиск на любой строке, только на строке, где символы отсортированы.

Comment: И ещё, снова повторю, в строке символы идут от 0, то есть в строке `Toschibaabr`, символ `s` находится на позиции 2.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, тоже были мысли по поводу этого(отсортированного массива)... Тогда придется уточнять у преподавателя что конкретно он хотел в задании.. Или придется писать метод под двумерный массив чаров для сортировки, сохранении позиции отдельно и тогда прогонять через метод поиска и выдавать уже старую позицию. Спасибо

Comment: Нет смысла сортировать, если вам надо только позицию символа узнать. Тогда уже проще просто циклом пройтись по каждому сиволу в слове и сравинть этот символ из слова с искомым символом.

Comment: @tym32167 Да, вы правы, я также хотел сначала, но после прочтения задания засомневался, там стоит запрет на линейный поиск.. В общем осталось уточнить.. Спасибо все равно.. Что-то за сегодня да выучил)

Answer (score 1):

Бинарный поиск (он же дихотомический поиск) имеет смысл только для поиска в сортированном массиве. Вы пытаетесь искать в `String`, который по сути представляет собой несортированный массив `char` - неудивительно, что у вас ничего не получается.

В общем [учите матчасть](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA)